# Scala: Chaining futures, returning the first

Tags: scala, future

I have a scenario where I have a `Future[Something]`: `a` which *when successful* needs to trigger a second `Future[Unit]`: `b`. I want to chain `a` and `b` together but I only care that `a` succeeds. if `b` fails I can just log an error and leave it at that:

So far I have:

```
def updateSomething(something: Something): Future[Something] = {
    val eventual: Future[Something] = repository.update(something)
    eventual.onSuccess({
      case updated =>
        repository.audit(updated.id, "Update successful")
          .onFailure({
            case throwable: Throwable => Logger.error("Audit failed", throwable)
          })
        Logger.info("Update Complete")
    })
    eventual
}
```

But this does not link the lifecyles of the `update` and the `audit` together. e.g when I `Await.result(service.updateSomething(...), duration)` there is no guarantee the `repository.audit` future has completed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`flatMap` is your friend. You can just use a for-comprehension + recover:

```
for {
  a <- executeA()
  _ <- executeB(b).recover{case e => println(e); Future.unit } // awaits B to complete
} yield a
```

Answer (score 0):

Also you can use more friendly form:

```
execudeA().flatMap(a =>
  executeB().recover { case e => println(e); () }.map(_ => a)
)
```

Answer (score 0):

also, you can just use a val

```
val = a <- executeA()
a.andThen{ case _ => executeB(b).recover{case e => println(e)} }
a //and return a
```